# What is the rva and base address in the portable executable format?

Tags: windows, format, executable, disassembly, portable-executable

I need help to understand these concepts.
I understand that the rva is an offset from the base address. But Its relative to what in a file? I understood it was from where the image will be loaded in memory, but in the executable file itself, an rva is relative to what? The beggining of the file, so the file Id at the start?
Thanks for reading :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Relative Virtual Addresses", relative to what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848982/relative-virtual-addresses-relative-to-what)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, usually from the start of the file. There are probably a couple of exceptions when you get deeper into specific parts of a file. You will generally find them when reading the documentation:

> MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK.OffsetToEntries:
>
> **The offset, in bytes, from the beginning of the MESSAGE_RESOURCE_DATA structure** to the MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY structures in this MESSAGE_RESOURCE_BLOCK. The MESSAGE_RESOURCE_ENTRY structures contain the message strings.